How do you start a line-by-line profiling with JetBrains dotTrace 2024.1 using the API?
I'm trying to profile the performance of a class in an .NET application. I have JetBrains dotTrace 2024.1, which can profile: Sampling, Timeline, Tracing and Line-by-Line.
I want to start and end a line-by-line profiling programmatically from within the application using the API.
However the documentation doesn't say how to configure the profiling to line-by-line. Does anyone know how to do this?
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/2024.1/Profiling_Guidelines__Advanced_Profiling_Using_dotTrace_API.html#self-profiled-applications

According to JetBrains it is not possible to use Tracing and Line-by-Line profiling types via the dotTrace self-profiling API because these profiling types do not support Attach mode.
This is currently not stated in the documentation, but will be added.
